# MVC4 Authorize for specific user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have very simple forum where I create posts. Now I would like to make edit function with authorization only for user that created post and Administrator.

For Admin only it's easy:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,Moderator")]

@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator")){}
```

But I'm not sure how to make it for specific logged in user.

Comment: Add the User to a Role. That way in the future when that user is away, you can assign it to someone else.

Comment: That wouldn't work. He's looking to have an edit function for a post where only the creator of each user (and the Admins) have access to the post. Adding a User to the Role won't work as it will be the same method that always gets called, and the Post (and Creator) will be changing on a call by call basis.

Answer (score 1):

Do the authorization as you currently have it. That will take care of Admins and Moderators.

Then, do something like this when retrieving the post from your data storage. Either like this:

```
var post = repository.Posts.Where(p => p.Id == parameterPostId && p.CreatedBy == CurrentUser.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
if (post == null) {
    // User didn't create it. return false or unauthorized.
}
else {
    // Continue on with returning the post.
}
```

Or, you could also do this to make sure that the post exists at all in the database:

```
var post = repository.Posts.Where(p => p.Id == parameterPostId).FirstOrDefault();
if (post == null) 
    // You know the post doesn't exist at all.
}
else if (post.CreatedBy != CurrentUser.UserName) {
    // The post was made by someone else, so unauthorized
}
else {
    // Show the user their post.
}
```